# How does the following linked list work in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

Following is the code to create a linked list from scratch in python.Only the append function is done here:

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
class LinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element
```

I do not completely understand how the lines work

```
            current = current.next
        current.next = new_element
```

I realize that the first line is to move along the linked list(like an increment) and the second line is to link the address of the previous node to the next element of the linked list.But could someone please explain how this actually works on a deeper level as in what is assigned to what (what kind of variables they are, assignment an address or a value)

Comment: Are you asking how Python variables/assignment work?

Comment: Just read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? The `LinkedList` object just keeps a reference to the first element. In order to append, the while loop needs to follow all the `next` links in order to find the last one.

Comment: Draw a diagram of the object on a piece of paper and then execute the code by hand. Then you will be enlightened.

Comment: all variables are python objects , you might need to check referencing objects in python to have a clear understanding .

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks a ton!! I found a great link in the link you provided which helped me a lot. http://pythontutor.com

Answer (score 0):

well '`current=current.next` statement means you are going to the node which contains address of None in its next field because that will be the terminating node of your linked list and after that you have to add the new node which will be done by the statement `current.next=element(7)` See the program given below it will show you how to create a singly linked list in python... Hope it helps you.... and for [insertion at beginning or any other position in linked list click here](http://www.plexinfo.com/2017/05/program-for-insertion-and-deletion-at-linked-list-python.html)

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self,data,next=None):
   self.data=data
   self.next=None

class LinkedList():
   def __init__(self):
   self.head=None

   def insert(self,data):
      if(self.head==None):
         n=Node(data)
         self.head=n
         return
      else:
         current=self.head
         while(current.next!=None):
             current=current.next
         current.next=Node(data)
         return
   def printing(self):
      if(self.head==None):
         print "Linked List is empty"
      else:
         current=self.head
         while(current!=None):
            print current.data,
            current=current.next
myLinkList=LinkedList()
myLinkList.insert(18)
myLinkList.insert(20)
myLinkList.insert(56)
myLinkList.insert(50)
print("\n\nThe created Singly Linked List is: \n\n")
myLinkList.printing()
print("\n\n")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had understood what you are saying ,what I wanted to know was  how the addressing worked. I found this great resource which helped me strengthen my understanding. 
http://pythontutor.com